# Laravel eloquent: OrderBy special condition

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

I am creating a small news system and these are the tables I have available:

**News Table**

| id | title | text |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | News 1 | - |
| 2 | News 2 | - |
| 3 | News 3 | - |
| 4 | News 4 | - |
| 5 | News 5 | - |

**Category Table**

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | film |
| 2 | anime |
| 3 | book |
| 4 | series |
| 5 | TV series |
| 6 | police |
| 7 | crime |

**Topic Table**

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | film |
| 2 | anime |
| 3 | book |
| 4 | marvel |
| 5 | TV series |
| 6 | police |
| 7 | crime |

**Related post/category Table**

| id | post_id | category_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 2 |
| 3 | 2 | 3 |
| 4 | 2 | 2 |
| 5 | 3 | 5 |
| 6 | 3 | 4 |
| 7 | 4 | 5 |
| 8 | 4 | 6 |
| 9 | 5 | 5 |
| 10 | 5 | 7 |

**Related post/topic Table**

| id | post_id | topic_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 | 3 |
| 3 | 3 | 5 |
| 4 | 4 | 5 |
| 5 | 5 | 7 |

When writing a post, both categories and topics must be assigned. Topics and categories are the same thing but with a difference: you can assign unlimited categories but only 1 topic.

When I search for posts by category I get the list of posts containing that category. What I would like is to put first the posts that have the topic corresponding to the search made and then all the others.

If I run the following query

```
$search = 'TV series';

$query = News::with([
    'category_related',
    'topic_related'
])
->whereHas('category_related', function($query) use ($search){

    $query->where('name', 'like', '%'.$search.'%');
        
})
->paginate(20);
```

I get this list:

1. News 5
2. News 4
3. News 3

I would like this list:

1. News 4
2. News 3
3. News 5

In the second list I would like to obtain, news number 5 is in last position because the topic is different from the search 'TV series'.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance

**EDIT**

- Filter news items by category
- I check whether the searched category also corresponds to a topic
- If the topic check is successful I take those news items and put them first
- List all other news items

Comment: What do you need the pivot table post/topic for if you can only assign one topic?

Comment: I don't understand. You sort by created_by of the news table (which you did not give us but I assume the order is the same as these of the ids) and that is what you get. Also what do you mean by "different from the search made"?

Comment: @volkerschulz I will need it later when more topics can be assigned

Comment: @Henning I have put a simple sorting to make it clear how I would like to obtain the list. The second list puts those with the topic "TV series" as the first news item and then the news items with a different topic. I hope I have been clearer

Comment: @Danilo But how should the topic affect the order if you search in the categories and order by the news? Try ->orderBy('topic.id')

Comment: @Henning I simply want the news items that are shown first to be those that have a topic equal to the search and then the other news items.

Comment: @Danilo I think, you were mixing up categories and topics in your initial question.
Sounds like you should search in the topics and do a union afterwards but I am afroid getting only more confused...

Comment: Is `$search` populated with a value from `categories.name` or free text entered by the user? Are the `id` and `name` values in the `categories` and `topics` tables actually synchronised or do we need to check `categories.name = topics.name`? Please make sure your question is consistent. You have referenced the table `News Table`, yet in your code you have `Posts::with`.

Comment: @user1191247 search populated with a value entered by the user. I have found the solution and will post it tomorrow so I can explain the end result in detail.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a custom search order, you need to use `FIELD()`. As far as I know, there's no eloquent counterpart for that, so you need to use `orderByRaw()` as follows:

```
orderByRaw('FIELD(topic_id, 5) DESC, created_at ASC')
```

if you wanted results for topic_id 5 first and then all other, sorted by created_at.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I will also try this solution!

Answer (score 0):

In case I got you correct, this should do it:

```php
$search = 'TV series';

$query = Posts::with([
    'category_related',
    'topic_related'
])
->whereHas('category_related', function($query) use ($search){

    $query->where('name', 'like', '%'.$search.'%');
        
})
->orderBy('news.id', 'desc')
->orderBy('topic.id')
->paginate(20);
```

The trick is, first sort by the latest news and after that order by the topic.
The other way around it would NOT work.

**EDIT:**
I didn't get it right. As I now understand the search muste be done in the topic_related table. Then the result has to be UNION ALLed with the news that did not match the search.

That is what says. But I believe it is still not what he really wants.
Please say it again in short clear sentences without mixing up categories and topics. Where do you wand to search? What do you want to order by? Isn't category and topic the same (at least as you use it)?

Sorry, no offense. I might be the problem here.

Good luck!

Comment: If I got them right, they want all news with a specific topic id first (the one that was searched) and then all other posts with different topic ids.

Comment: @ volkerschulz Yes, exactly!

Comment: I think you are right. Now I am confused what the difference between topic and category is. The original post already had an orderBy...

Comment: @Henning Thank you very much! I will try your solution right away!

Comment: @Danilo This will not do what you want because I did not get your problem right when I wrote it.

Comment: @Henning No problem. I will try to explain myself better. I edit the post by putting a more detailed example

Comment: @Henning I have edited the post by putting a list of what I would like. I hope it is clearer.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution and here I try to explain how I did it.

First I run a query to get the list of news items in a category. The selection of the category is made by the user.

In the following example I enter the category manually, just to show how it works:

```
$search = 'TV series';

$query = News::with([
    'category_related',
    'topic_related'
])
->whereHas('category_related', function($query) use ($search){

    $query->where('name', $search);
        
})
->orderBy(' created_at', 'desc')
->paginate(20);
```

Then I created a resource:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Resources;

use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\JsonResource;

class NewsListResource extends JsonResource{

    public function toArray($request){
        
        return [
            'id' => $this->id,
            'title' => $this->title,
            'topic_id' => !empty($this->topic_related) ? $this->topic_related->id : null,
        ];

    }
    
}
```

In the created resource, I check whether the relationship with the "topics" has a result and if it does, I print the id relating to the "topic".

Now I use the resource with sortByDesc method:

```
$data = NewsListResource::collection($query)->sortByDesc('topic_id')->values();
```

I simply get the list of news items, reorder it according to the topic id (so that news items containing a topic are placed first).

I hope I have been clear in my explanation

**Other Solution**

```
// Count topic related
$query->withCount(['topic_related as count_topic' => function($query) use($search){
    $query->where('name', $search);
}]);

// Order
$query->orderByDesc('count_topic')->orderBy('created_at', 'desc');
```

Comment: I may be misunderstanding your code, but doesn't this just check for any related topic id, instead of checking that the topic name matches the found category name? In your question you stated _"put first the posts that have the topic corresponding to the search made"_.

Comment: @user1191247 I filter the news by category. If the 'topic' assigned to the news item matches the searched category, it must give it priority and show it first

Comment: Your _"NewsListResource"_ solution does not check that the topic and category match. Your _"Other Solution"_ does check that the topic name matches `$search`. Make sure your junction tables are indexed in both directions - `(post_id, category_id)` and `(category_id, post_id)`.

Comment: @user1191247 The new solution I posted works perfectly. I just need the Resource to get the data array and that's it!